# How do I set a webhook up to forward small JSON payloads to my code?

Tags: json, bots, webhooks, kik

I'm fairly new to programming so please bear with me. I'm working on a bot for Kik, and the docs say

> When a user sends your bot a message, your webhook will be called with a JSON payload with this structure:

All I need to do is receive a JSON POST and put it into a file that my code can call.

Answer (score 1):

A webhook is an API endpoint in your application that you create. Kik provides two libraries to make building your bot easier. A Python pip package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kik and an npm node package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kikinteractive/kik/

They also have example applications in them. You could host on app-engine or heroku.